# Retrieve ETW Provider Manifest for a registered provider

Tags: c#, etw

I would like to retrieve manifest xml file for Provider "Microsoft-Windows-HttpService".

I am using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing library to consume ETW events in my .Net application.

This library has some built-in parsers like KernelTraceEventParser, ClrTraceEventParser. But it does not have parser Http Service. I am trying to create new parser for this.

I tried below commands to generate manifest

```
perfView /onlyProviders=*Microsoft-Windows-HttpService collect
```

and from generated .zip file, ran below command to generate manifest.

```
perfView /noGui userCommand DumpEventSourceManifests PerfViewData.etl.zip
```

now used TraceParserGen to generate CSharp code

```
TraceParserGen  ManifestFileName
```

But this gives me error:
Reading manifest file Microsoft-Windows-HttpService.manifest.xml
Error: Error Microsoft-Windows-HttpService.manifest.xml(42): Undefined Id SrvdFrmCache

I tried to create manual classes for few events also and it reads the event but not able to read payload.

Please let me know how I generate correct manifest for this provider and generate parser.

Comment: the manifest data are part of the .manifest files of the HTTP.sys in WinSxS folder. Here for the file from Windows 8: "C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-http_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_058aa3ada29f230f.manifest"

Comment: Thanks for guiding to the exact folder and file.

Answer (score 7):

The DumpEventSOurceManifests command should have only generated manifest.xml files for any System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource that were active in the given trace.   Since HttpService is not an EventSource (it is implemented by the OS without using even .NET) that will not work

There is a command

```
PerfView userCommand DumpRegisteredManifest Microsoft-Windows-HttpService
```

That will do the same for any ETW provider that registers itself with the OS (most OS providers do, including HttpService).